# Porting Android code to BlackBerry naitivly

Tags: java, android, c++, blackberry, telegram

I am trying to port an Android application to BlackBerry 10 and make it look naitive. I have written all the QML for the app but I cannot seem to get the code to work. Do I need to translate the Java into C++ and if I do, do I have to do it manually or would an automatic one do?

Also my application has many different classes which I am not sure how to integrate with the BlackBerry layout.

I am trying to port the open source messenger Telegram, if that's any use. http://telegram.org/source/

Comment: I assume it has to do with https://telegram.org/blog/blackberry-contest ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do a proper port and know C++ and Java, a full rewrite would be best. You can probably copy a lot of code from the Java source, but there's no way an automated converter or direct copy would ever work in C++.

Most of the processes in BlackBerry are the same as in Android, all you'd really need to do is rewrite all the UI code and handlers to fit the [BlackBerry Native SDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/)